# Interpretation of a Problem involving permutations

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

[USAMO 1999 submission, Titu Andreescu]

> Let $n$ be an odd integer greater than $1$. Find the number of permutations $p$ of the set $\{ 1, 2, …, n\}$ for which  $$\def\x#1{\lvert p(#1)-#1\rvert} \x1+\x2+\cdots+\x n = \frac{n^2-1}2.$$

[(original scan)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkrLB.png)

I dont need an answer, just an interpretation of the problem.

What does it mean by:

> number of permutations

?? I though permutations were numbers, but then he defines $p(n)$? I am not sure?

Answer (score 2):

A permutation $p$ on the set $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ is a bijection $p : \{1,2,\ldots, n\} \to \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of a permutation of $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ as a bijection (one-to-one and onto; invertible) function from $[n]$ to $[n]$.

So, if have the permutation

$$p = \begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 3 &4 \\ 3&2&1&4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1& 2& 3 &4 \\ p(1)&p(2)&p(3)&p(4)\end{pmatrix},$$

we can see that it sends $1$ to $p(1) = 3$, etc.